# hibernate - strange error on foreign key and primary key when updating

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc

I receive a strange error that I can't reproduce in eclipse but appears on server.

Says:

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 
update public.user set 
    is_at='[B@136ef65', 
    user_name='elk', 
    password='33e79218965eb72c92a549dd5a330113', 
    location_precision=NULL, 
    location_simulated=NULL, 
    active=NULL, 
    last_seen_at='2013-02-20 08:13:45.992000 +01:00:00', 
    app_uuid=NULL, 
    avatar_url='http://server.org/img/avatars/10.png', 
    email='mail@mail.com', 
    score=NULL, 
    phrase='hibernate fail', 
    state=NULL, 
    reputation=NULL, 
    reputation_desc=NULL, 
    privacy_settings='visibleForAll', 
    gender='male', 
    email_verified='1', 
    geom='SRID=4326;POINT(2.209740161895752 41.400447845458984)' 
where user_id='[B@19ee400' 
was aborted.  Call getNextException to see the cause.
```

Following by

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: id to load is required for loading
```

It fails because (hibernate?) fails to convert the attribute is_at and user_id to strings. It seems to try to parametrize the query with sort of a binary representation on the object.

Relevant hbm.xml snippet:

```
<id name="userId" type="java.lang.Long">
    <column name="user_id" />
    <generator class="sequence">
        <param name="sequence">user_user_id_seq</param>
    </generator>
</id>
<many-to-one name="checkin" class="org.server.entity.Checkin" fetch="select">
    <column name="is_at" />
</many-to-one>
```

I cannot see nothing strange, maybe more eyes see more? The strange thing is that in my IDE is working. Somebody had ever seen similar error?

hibernate: 3.6.2
version tomcat 6.0.33
java openjdk 1.6.0.18
postgresql: 8.3.9

UPDATE:

The Java code for this:

```
// queryHistory is to be persisted
// user is not null 
queryHistory.setUser(user);
queryHistory.setApiKey(apiKey);


// create point
Coordinate coordinate = new Coordinate(queryHeader.getLocLon(),queryHeader.getLocLat());
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = new GeometryFactory(new PrecisionModel(),4326);
Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(coordinate);

queryHistory.setGeom(point);

if(user!=null) {
        user.setGeom(point);
        user.setLastSeenAt(new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
        hSession.update(user);
}

hSession.persist(queryHistory);
t.commit();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: oh, man. hibernate 3 is a previous century. You have `user id type="java.lang.Long"` and why do you pass string '[B@19ee400'?

Comment: Hi Viacheslav, yeah I should update. I have a hibernate-spatial dependance, I saw they have now a compatible release. Anyway it works in eclipse. What's wrong with `user id type="java.lang.Long"`? The string `'[B@19ee400'` creates hibernate, I'm setting the object correctly.

Comment: How do you generate that HQL code?

Comment: What you see is actually SQL that hibernate generates. I simply do `session.update(user)`

Comment: I have updated the question with a code snippet.

Comment: Please show the mapping of is_at in both tables